# how to split time into days hours minutes seconds from a text string

Tags: excel, string, numbers

I've got a string of time appearing as text that I need to convert to numbers. Here is an example:

[image: 1]

How do I convert the string into separate columns. One column for days, one for hours, etc.?

Comment: 2 days 19 hours 13 minutes 12 seconds 867 milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the durations as titles and use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(LOWER($A2)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'"&LOWER(B$1)&"')]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")
```

Put that in B2 and copy over.

[image]